Interstellar mice rates?
The following passage is from Terry Pratchett's Discworld: Light Fantastic:

'Endlessly roaming through the universe,' mused Twoflower.
'That's right. Mind you, there is a saving on the rates.'
'Rates?'
'Yes, they're—' the shopkeeper paused, and wrinkled his forehead. 'I can't quite
remember, it was such a long time ago. Rates, rates —'
'Very large mice?'
'That's probably it.'

I understand that they are discussing interstellar travelling rates but what do mice have to do with that?
I thought it might be a similar pun as echo-gnomics in the previous book (which translated to economics), but after 20 or so minutes of searching I haven't turned up anything meaningful Very large mice could translate to.
Can anyone make heads or tails of this?

Rats. Very large mice.

Rates > Rats > Very large mice

[literature.se] is probably a better place to ask questions about dialogue.

Back in the day in the UK, "non-roaming" homeowners used to pay Rates based on the "rateable value" of the property. Now rebranded as Council Tax / Community Charge.

"Rates" in 20th century British parlance is what is called "property tax" in other places - a tax paid by owners of buildings to the municipality they are in. A trans-dimensional travelling shop would easily be able to avoid paying such taxes by never staying in the same place for very long, hence the "saving on the rates".
Twoflower is notorious for "translating" words as something that sounds like the word he means; so "economics" becomes "the reflected sound of underground spirits" (echo-gnomics). He appears to have done the same here. "Very large mice" are rats, which sounds like "rates". Twoflower thinks the shop owner is saving on them. The shop owner is confused enough (probably because of constant traveling through the dimensions) that he assumes Twoflower is right.
